# is there a multiple format specifier in Python?

Tags: python

I have a data table 44 columns wide that I need to write to file.  I don't want to write:

```
outfile.write("%i,%f,%f,$f ... )\n" % (i, a,b,c ...))
```

In Fortran you can specify multiple format specifiers easily:

```
write (*,"(3f8.3)") a,b,c
```

Is there a similar capability in Python?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
>>> "%d " * 3
'%d %d %d '
>>> "%d " * 3 % (1,2,3)
'1 2 3 '
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, I didn't know this.  It also worked when I tried it as part of a print in a program:

    print "%d " * 3 % (1, 2, 3)

Comment: Note that the * operator isn't specific to format specifiers; it tells Python to duplicate the preceding sequence X times.  Since a string is a sequence, and format specifiers are just strings ...

Comment: @ChrisB.: Not "_duplicate X times_", but "_multiply X times_", I believe :) The former could be understood as if `"%d " * 3` would be equal to `((("%d " * 2) * 2) * 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about

```
format= "%i" + ",%f"*len(row) + "\n"
outfile.write( format % ([i]+row))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not exactly the same, but you can try something like this:

```
values=[1,2.1,3,4,5]  #you can use variables instead of values of course
outfile.write(",".join(["%f" % value for value in values]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I think it'd be much better to do something like:

```
outfile.write(", ".join(map(str, row)))
```

...which isn't what you asked for, but is better in a couple of ways.